# how to read input to an infinite loop function but not pause the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing a program to track the prices of amazon products for which the user provides URL of the product. I have first read two URLs as input and stored them as objects in a list then at last I run the list of objects one by one to track the prices further but I would like to add more URLs furthermore even while the function is being run but without pausing the function. I have attached the full program I have written yet below, Thanks.

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

class PriceTrack:

    productMethods=[]

    def __init__(self,url):
        HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
        source=requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text
        
        #title
        soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        title=soup.find(id='productTitle')
        ProductTitle=title.get_text().strip()
        
        #price
        price=soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').text[2:]
        result = re.sub(r"[,₹]","", price, flags = re.I)
        price,_=result.split('.')
        price=float(price)
        
        #pricelist
        price_list=[]
        self.ProductTitle=ProductTitle
        self.Price=price
        price_list.append(price)
        self.PriceList=price_list

    def trackAndadd(self):
        HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
        source=requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text
        
        soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        #price
        price=soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').text[2:]
        result = re.sub(r"[,₹]","", price, flags = re.I)
        price,_=result.split('.')
        price=float(price)

        if price!=self.PriceList[-1]:
            self.PriceList.append(price)

        print(self.ProductTitle,self.Price,self.PriceList)
        print()
    
    @classmethod
    def Addproduct(cls,url):
        product=cls(url)
        PriceTrack.productMethods.append(product)
        print(str(product))



url=input('Enter the url :')
PriceTrack.Addproduct(url)

url=input('Enter the url :')
PriceTrack.Addproduct(url)

while True:
    for i in PriceTrack.productMethods:
        #func=str(i)+'.trackAndadd'
        eval('i.trackAndadd()')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [Scrapy Python package](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) which does what you are looking to do and then some. You will probably have to rewrite your code a bit to fit their framework, but yielding initial links and then yielding additional links to be added as the code execution goes on is the bread and butter of Scrapy (see for example [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links))